# Dynamically adding method from an instance to another using MethodType

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to decorate class instances with new methods. But if the decorator adds a method from it's own self it gives me an error

```
TypeError: myMethod() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

To give a minimal example, say I have a class MyElement I cannot modify and a Decorator adding a method from itself to instances of MyElement

```
class MyElement(object):
    def __init(self):
        self._name = "MyElement"

class Decorator(object):

    def myMethod(self):
        print(self._name)

    def decorate(self, element):
        element.myMethod = MethodType(self.myMethod, element)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = Decorator()
    p = MyElement()

    d.decorate(p)
    p.myMethod()
```

This gives me the error above. Altough If I change decorate to this it works :

```
def decorate(self, element): 
    element.myMethod = MethodType(self.myMethod.__func__, element)
```

Could somebody explain what actually MethodType is doing? And why the **func** flag si necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `MethodType` to bind your `Decorator`'s `myMethod` method to another object. This isn't working, because when you access it with `self.myMethod`, you're already getting a bound method. The first binding passes the `Decorator` object as `self` and the second binding causes the exception when it tries to pass the `MyElement` instance as a second argument.

There are a few ways you could work around this. It's not clear which one would be best for you because your `myMethod` example doesn't do anything with `self`.

One option is to access `myMethod` through the `Decorator` class, rather than via `self`. This means it will be unbound (until you wrap it in `MethodType` of course). In this version, the `self` values seen in `myMethod` will be the `MyElement` instance, not the `Decorator` (which may be surprising to somebody reading the code). In Python 2, unbound methods had a special check that `self` was the right type, and so this wouldn't work.

```
def decorate(self, element):
    element.myMethod = MethodType(Decorator.myMethod, element)
```

Another option would be to save the bound method you get with `self.myMethod` as a variable on `element` without trying to bind it again. With this approach, `self` will still be the decorator object, even though the method is being called via a `MyElement` object.

```
def decorate(self, element):
    element.myMethod = self.myMethod
```

A final option is to leave the `decorate` method as it is, but add an extra argument to `myMethod`. This will allow both the `Decorator` instance (as `self`) and the `MyElement` instance to be passed in:

```
def myMethod(self, element):
    print("{} is decorated by {}".format(element, self))
```

Comment: Thanks for very accurate answer, now I understant MethodType. `element.myMethod = Decorator.myMethod` works for me.